# Twitter Bootstrap popover hover causes maximum stack size exceeded

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
%a.popup-trigger{
    href: "#", 
    "data-trigger" => "hover", 
    "data-html" => 'true', 
    "data-content" => "<img src='/assets/image.png'>"
}
  Show Image
```

And then:

```
$('.popup-trigger').popover();
```

It works as expected when I hover into the link (it shows the popup with the image and no errors in the console). When I hover out, the popup disappears but then the console shows the error `maximum stack size exceeded`

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the stack trace for the error?

Comment: I only get "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" and then it repeats "b.event.remove" until it gives up.

Comment: Something funky going on. Are you able to pause JS execution during the stack overflow event? Another thing to check: how many .popup-trigger elements are there?

Comment: I can't pause it (it blows up almost instantly). There's only one .popup-trigger in the page.

Comment: Does it happen when  putting the popup on other elements?

Comment: I think the popup only works with links. It doesn't work with a button, label, paragraph, or div.

Comment: Right, sorry, I mean, try it on a different link element. Put a link element near the root of the DOM, see if the exception still occurs.

Comment: I removed all elements from the page except the link but it still fails. I should be a conflict of scripts right? The console error doesn't give me a file.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you mentioned you removed all elements from the page except the one link, then called .popover() on that, and it still failed.

This suggests something external is wrong: are you linking to the latest Bootstrap (3.0+) and JQuery (2.0+)?

I'd suggest creating a fiddle to reproduce the problem with your code. This will allow you to narrow down the real problem.